# Всегда зажатая кнопка

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-button

Как сделать так, чтобы программа зажимала обычную кнопку в Android Studio? Не визиуально зажимала, а чтобы она делала тоже самое, что и человек при нажимании кнопки, только сама.

Comment: Вопрос поставлен довольно странно, но если речь идёт о мобильном приложении, то не проще просто при создании программы вызывать функцию которая висит на кнопке. Если же речь идёт о Android Studio,  то я не могу понять что именно вы спрашиваете))

Comment: Напишите более подробно, что вы хотите сделать, а лучше покажите код

Comment: @AndrewGoroshko речь идёт о Android Studio. Я сделал кнопку. Как сделать так, чтобы она была зажата автоматически?

Comment: я сейчас переформулирую вопрос: вы рассказываете про кнопку в IDE или в программе для мобильного устройства, которую вы сделали в этой IDE?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для вашей задачи подойдет обычный слушатель изменений в поле ввода. Кнопка это конечно круто, но я думаю что ее использовать не обязательно. Для `EditText` есть слушатель который принимает строку и если она соответствует какому-то заранее известному слову то программа осуществляет переход на другое активити. Вот например:

```
//Инициализируем наши элементы:
mEditTxt = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edittext);
```

дальше вешаем слушатель изменений текста:

`mEditTxt .addTextChangedListener(textWatcher);`

ну и сам слушатель:

```
//Создаем экземпляр TextWatcher:
 private final TextWatcher textWatcher = new TextWatcher() {
 public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
 }

 public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

 }

 //Задаем действия для TextView после смены введенных в EditText символов:
 public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

 }
 };
```

Реализация Text Watcher происходит довольно просто, благодаря своим 3 методам:

```
-beforeTextChanged () - работает до изменений в тексте;
-onTextChanged () - работает во время ввода текста;
-afterTextChanged () - работает после ввода текста, уведомляет, что текст был изменен.
```

соответственно вам нужен тот метод который будет работать после изменения текста:

```
public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
if (s.length() > 0) {
String word = s.getText.toString().trim();
switch (word){
case "машина":
Intent int1 = new Intent(YourActivity.this, CarActivity.class)
startActivity(int1)
break;
case "трактор":
break;
}}
//Иначе:
else{
// выводим сообщение что нужно что-то ввести
}}}
```

как видите здесь есть функция `после того как текст изменен`. Там вы считываете символы с вашего поля для ввода, и дальше делаете сравнение. Конечно можно заморочится с кнопкой, но я думаю что можно решить проблему гораздо быстрее и проще. Вот [ссылка](http://learn-android.ru/news/ispolzuem_ehlement_textwatcher/2015-04-11-87.html) на первоисточник.

Возможно есть ошибки в правильности использования функций и переменных, нету сейчас возможности открыть студию для проверки, но смысл должен быть понятен.

Если все-таки вам нужно как-то сделать программу с кнопкой, то напишите в коментариях, и будем думать в сторону кнопки.

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/83212/discussion-on-answer-by-andrew-goroshko---).

Comment: Наконец-то, я просто не видел чтобы кнопка появилась для перемещения) спасибо